# Book about history of the foundational crisis of mathematics

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, math-history, foundations

Recently I got interested in the [foundational crisis of mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundations_of_mathematics#:%7E:text=and%20mathematical%20induction.-,Foundational%20crisis,for%20proper%20foundations%20for%20mathematics.). As a theoretical physicist (so, not a mathematician), I am looking for a book that gives a historical take on the matter while also providing a basic understanding of the logic and math concepts that sparked the crisis and those that ultimately solved it.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Morris Kline, [Mathematics: The Loss of Certainty (1980)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics:_The_Loss_of_Certainty) as well as Marcus Giaquinto, [The Search for Certainty (2002)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Search_for_Certainty_A_Philosophical/gyNbrpYXzxoC).

Comment: The references on the Wikipedia page you linked might be a good place to start. It's generally a little hard to find a "historical take" considering that it is a relatively modern and continuing crisis; your statement on "[concepts] that ultimately solved it" is not exactly correct.

Comment: Also useful SEP's [Philosophy of Mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/philosophy-mathematics/) with bibliography and link to other related entries.

Comment: Logicomix is a fun read also: https://www.amazon.com/Logicomix-search-truth-Apostolos-Doxiadis/dp/1596914521

Comment: This might be suited for hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: An excellent older book is Mathematical Logic and the Foundations of Mathematics by G.T. Kneebone (1963). It was reprinted by Dover in 2003 but seems now to be out-of-print. There are used copies on Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in a history of both foundational questions and their mathematical background, there is a book of one of the most prominent historians of mathematics, Ivor Grattan-Guinness, *The search for Mathematical Roots. 1870-1940- Logic, Set Theories and the Foundations of Mathematics from Cantor to Russel to Godel*, Princeton University Press, 2000.

This book is really profound and particular, because it gives a detailed account of the mathematical aspects, not only of philosophical aspects, and a comprehensive treatment of the history of logic in that period.

As for the philosophical and foundational aspects, there are many good books that introduce to philosophy of mathematics, as books indicated above in the comments.
I can mention in particular a source book, a classical reference, well-known selected readings book, where you can find classical important articles about the subject, that is Benacerraf P., Putnam H. (eds.), *Philosophy of Mathematics-* *Selected readings*, Cambridge University Press, 2° ed., 1982.

[edit] I see that you are Italian, I too. So you can read also, in Italian, Gabriele Lolli, *La guerra dei trent'anni (1900-1930)-Da Hilbert a Gödel*, ETS, 2011.